# Run time error 1004, The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type

Tags: excel, vba

Im working on a project where we are going from Windows Server 2003 32bit, with Office 2010 to Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit with Office 2010 32bit.

The problem we get is with a Excel workbook that gets a VBS runtime error 1004. 
I dont know programming that well, so I was wondering whats wrong.

The command that gets the error is the .Publish (true)

The code:

```
Sheets("mail") .Select
With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceSheet, _
    "L:\Data\HBV_HTML\Ny-hbv.mht", _
    "mail", "", xlHtmlStatic, "Ny-hbv", "")
    .Publish (True) <- Gets highlighted
    .AutoRepublish = False
End With
```

Is there any changes to the programming that needs to be done to be able to get this working again?

Thanks

Regards
Andre

Answer (score 0):

Your range is empty. Look in the [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823068(v=office.15).aspx) on what each field should be like. Instead of the empty `""` try adding the `Source` with the cells range you want, maybe [EntireRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836836(v=office.15).aspx) or something similar.